# Error when installing .msi - needs to be installed on local drive

Tags: windows-10, installation, windows-11, windows-installer

I have an MSI file I'm trying to install (for the Bose SoundTouch program). However, when I press 'install' after selecting the directory that it should be installed in, I get an error - that the program has to be installed on a local drive. Which doesn't make sense, because I am installing it on the C disk.

I've seen 2 solutions - to run either of these 2 commands from cmd as administrator:

`msiexec /i "msi path"`

or

`msiexec /i "msi path" WIXUI_DONTVALIDATEPATH="1"`

But when running `msiexec /i "msi path"` I still get the same error, and when running it with `WIXUI_DONTVALIDATEPATH="1"` I am not able to click the 'install' button.

I am running Windows 10 64 bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command worked for me:

```
msiexec /i "msi path" WIXUI_DONTVALIDATEPATH="1" /qb
```

Just open cmd as administator, paste that in, and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Right click .MSI file then run as administrator. This should ensure .MSI installs correctly

Comment: I don't see a run as administrator often. Not sure if that's because I already installed it... But I did see someone suggest that, and someone else respond that they didn't see that option.